# In a TCP server - client connection using Poll(), do I need to set events by hand? I am never reaching POLLOUT to write to a socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I have established a connection between a client and a server in c using poll() on a single fd. I want for the client to receive a message when the server has something to send and vice versa.

As far as I know, poll() listens for events on file desctriptors. I am not clear though as to how these events (or revents) are triggered, to determine when it is time to send or receive on the fd.

I have tried using read and write (or send and recv for that matter) in a loop for the client side but they block, so I switched to poll() for the client side too.

On the client side, I am never getting to the `}else if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT)` part, meaning that the socket is never available to write to.

```
   //Create - bind - listen to a socket named listeningSocket

    struct pollfd fds[1];
    fds[0].fd = listeningSocket;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;


 if (poll(fds, 1, 3000)) {
            (client_sock = accept(listeningSocket, &client, (socklen_t *) &c));
            spdlog::info("Connection accepted");

            std::thread thread(&ConnectionHandler::Handle, std::ref(requestHandler), client_sock);
            thread.detach();

}
```

The client block

```
 while (true) {
        if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, 100) > 0)) {

            if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN ){
                recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0);
                printf("From Server : %s", buff);
                bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));

            }
        }else if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT){
            puts(buff);
            strcpy(buff, "HELLO WORLD");
            write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            break;
        }
    }
```

On connect, the server sends a welcoming message with `write()` to the client. The client `recv()`s this but then never gets its turn to right back to the server.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't the socket be ready to write to when there are no lingering data to be received on it?

Comment: You ignore the return value from `recv` which is never a good idea. Also, why `sizeof(buff)` to `write`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this example code has been stripped of many checks (e.g. the recv return value) and its scope is to be more of a library rather than a standalone programme (hence the sizeof(buff). You wouldn't know how big the message to send would be). Any thoughts or improvements are always welcome

Comment: If you don't know how big the message to send would be, how can you send it? Don't you need to know how many bytes you're sending to send the correct number of bytes?!

Answer (score 3):

Lets reformat your `while` loop to make it easier to read:

```cpp
while (true)
{
    if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, 100) > 0))
    {
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0);
            printf("From Server : %s", buff);
            bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        }
    }
    else if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT)
    {
        puts(buff);
        strcpy(buff, "HELLO WORLD");
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        break;
    }
}
```

It should now be apparent why your `POLLOUT` block is never executed - that `if` statement is only reached when `poll()` returns `<= 0`, which is not what you want.

You need this kind of logic instead:

```cpp
while (true)
{
    if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, 100) > 0))
    {
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN )
        {
            recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0);
            printf("From Server : %s", buff);
            bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        }
        else if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT)
        {
            puts(buff);
            strcpy(buff, "HELLO WORLD");
            write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which, when reformatted back to your original coding style, would look like this:

```cpp
while (true) {
    if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, 100) > 0)) {

        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN ){
            recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0);
            printf("From Server : %s", buff);
            bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));

        } else if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT){
            puts(buff);
            strcpy(buff, "HELLO WORLD");
            write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See the difference good formatting makes?

That being said, know that a socket enters a writable state as soon as it connects.  So your code is likely to send the client's greeting before waiting for the server's greeting.  If you need to wait for the server's greeting before replying, you have to actually read the greeting first, eg:

```cpp
while (true)
{
    if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, 100) > 0))
    {
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            rv = recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0);
            if (rv <= 0) break;
            printf("From Server : %.*s", rv, buff);

            if (/* the complete greeting has been read */) // MAY take multiple reads!
            {
                strcpy(buff, "HELLO WORLD");
                write(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it is not necessary to handle `POLLOUT` when using blocking sockets.  But if you are using non-blocking sockets instead, you are responsible for checking if `write()` fails with an `EWOULDBLOCK` error, and if so then buffer the data you tried to send that failed, as well as any subsequent data, until `POLLOUT` is reported, then you can send the buffered data (continuing to handle `EWOULDBLOCK` and `POLLOUT`) until the buffer is empty.  Only then can you send new data over the socket without handling `POLLOUT` again until a new `EWOULDBLOCK` error is reported. For example:

```cpp
int sendData(int fd, void *data, int len)
{
    char *pdata = (char *) buff;

    if (/* fd's buffer is empty */)
    {
        while (len > 0)
        {
            int rv = send(fd, pdata, len, 0);
            if (rv < 0)
            {
                if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                    return rv;
                break;
            }

            pdata += rv;
            len -= rv;
        }
    }

    if (len > 0)
    {
        // add pdata up to len bytes to fd's buffer...
    }

    return 0;
}

...

while (true)
{
    if ((rv = poll(fds, 1, 100) > 0))
    {
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            rv = recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0);
            if (rv <= 0) break;
            printf("From Server : %.*s", rv, buff);

            if (/* the complete greeting has been read */) // MAY take multiple reads!
            {
                strcpy(buff, "HELLO WORLD");
                sendData(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff));
            }
        }

        if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT)
        {
            char *pdata = ...; // fd's buffer data
            int len = ...; // fd's buffer length
            int sent = 0;

            while (len > 0)
            {
                rv = send(fd, pdata, len, 0);
                if (rv < 0)
                    break;

                pdata += rv;
                len -= rv;
                sent += rv;
            }

            if (sent > 0)
            {
                // remove sent bytes from fd's buffer...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `sendData()` any time you need to send any data to `fd`, instead of calling `write()`/`send()` directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. I indeed see how good formatting makes it easier to see mistakes indeed. 

I have a question on your answer; how would I know when I have received the whole thing? Thank you again for your time and effort!

Comment: @kaptsea that is what protocols are meant for. The sender has to format its messages in such a way that the receiver knows when each message has been received in full. For TCP, there are only 3 ways to do that: 1) send the message length before sending the message data. Read the length first, then read as many bytes as the length says. 2) send a unique terminator after the data. Keep reading until the terminator is received. 3) close the connection. Keep reading until disconnected. So you need to write your code to match whatever protocol the server is using.

Comment: So let me get this straight; I could beforehand decide that each message would end with a '\n' or be a certain length, and read - recv until either criterion is met? It's all MY decision? Aren't there some best practices on this? Which is the most common way to implement?

Comment: @kaptsea if you are writing both client and server, then yes, it is your decision, so use whatever suits your needs. Prefixing a length is good for variable length binary data, using a terminator is good for text-based protocols. Or you have protocols like HTTP and FTP, which use multiple techniques at the same time

Comment: Thank you so much for all this info and your time :) It was enlightening to say the least! I am grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `}` before the `else if`.
Then put it after the `else if`-block.

Comment: Well, that was enlightening :) Thank you so much, I have been missing that for hours!